# chef cookbook dependency on system software not on another cookbook

Tags: python, automation, chef-infra, orchestration

As part of a platform setup orchestration we are using our python package to install various software packages on a cluster of machines in cloud.

We have the following scenario:

1. Our python package initiates installation of certain software packages(say A,B,C) then simultaneously initiates installation of certain other (say D,E,F).
   (N.B:. D,E,F are through our chef cookbooks and A,B,C are through our python programs )
2. Our problem is that software D(installs through chef cookbook) depends on software A.
3. Since, D depends on A, cookbook for D does not find A in system and fails.

What I was thinking was, if we can have a dependency in chef cookbook saying that proceed only if A is found in system else wait!

Is it possible? are there any alternatives to above problem?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you manage all the packages from chef ? The only idea I can get off is a guard to not run the package resource is A is not present, testing the presence depend on what pckage you're talking about (system ? pip ? something else ?)

Comment: @Tensibai
yes, i was talking about hadoop packages(more precisely HDP repositories). 
guards worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied the following steps to solve my problem

1. Found the directory which gets created after installation of the independent software
2. waited for the directory to get created(using ruby block code for sleeping) and initiated the installation of dependent software thereafter to ensure the dependency is satisfied.

solved my issue..

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using [puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/). Whit puppet you can define required [resources](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html) (eg. [`package`](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#package)) and also define [relationships](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/ordering.html#language:-relationships-and-ordering) between resources.

E.g puppet manifest:

```
package { ["A", "B", "C", "E", "F"]:
  ensure => 'installed',
}

package { "D":
  ensure => 'installed',
  require => Package['A'],
}
```

**UPDATE:** updated example puppet manifest.

Comment: Also,
"""
 package { ["A", "B", "C"]:
  ensure => 'installed',
}
"""
while executing this, if it does not find A,B,C , will it wait for them or just throw an error saying "packages not found"?

Comment: You asked for alternatives, so I suggested puppet. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Chef. Puppet ensures that system is in state described in puppet manifest. So it will install packages "A","B","C","E","F", if are not installed yet. Puppet will install package "D" only when package "A" is already available in the system.

Comment: You're doing quite the same thing, in chef it will be by ordering, here you install all the packages with Puppet, the same is doable with chef. But that does not answer the question testing a package availability from the CM system before trying to install a package.

Comment: And in chef, you can just omit the 3 times definition and just loop over all packages in the needed order, Chef does nothing under the hood reordering what you described.